# Magento 2 How to send file to another server on predefined location?

Tags: magento2, csv, server-setup, file-upload

I am trying to upload a custom exported CSV to another server FTP on particular location.

> **Step 1:** *Added FTP Class in constructor*

```
protected $ftp;
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Ftp $ftp
){
    $this->ftp = $ftp;
}
```

> **Step 2:** *Build the FTP Connect*

```
$open = $this->ftp->open(
    array(
        'host' => 'myhostname',
        'user' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'ssl' => true,
        'passive' => true
    )
);
```

> **Step 3:** *Use the written function to upload a file to the server*

```
if ($open) {
    $fileName = 'myfile.csv';
    $content = file_get_contents(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR . '/pub/media/report' . $fileName);
    $this->ftp->write(self::FILE_NAME_ON_FTP, $content);
    $this->ftp->close();
}
```

The above code is working but I wanted to send file to particular location.

**Issue:**  I want to send file from my server path `pub/media/reports` to another server path `var/www/html/myfoldername/pub/media/reports`

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace this code in your 3rd step..

```
if ($open) {
    $fileName = 'myfile.csv';
    $content = file_get_contents(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR . '/pub/media/report' . $fileName);
    $this->ftp->cd("var/www/html/myfoldername/pub/media/reports/");
    $this->ftp->write(self::FILE_NAME_ON_FTP, $content);
    $this->ftp->close();
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing? there is a variable `VAR_DIR` it gives var directory path right?

Comment: Yes, Right. @temper

Comment: var directory which is located inside your Magento root directory.

Comment: Let me know if this will work for you.

Comment: I am doing this in cron and everytime cron gives success result, but no file transferred to FTP.

Comment: I think you need to check this path **self::FILE_NAME_ON_FTP**

Comment: Please concate this file in write function **"var/www/html/myfoldername/pub/media/reports/".self::FILE_NAME_ON_FTP** and check.

Comment: I did this , the issue was in ftp connection. it is nont coocting with ftp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100959/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-temper).

Comment: Approve my answer when you read it. Thanks. :)

Comment: The issue is not solved yet. I will approve it after fixixng the issue.

Comment: Okay thanks. @temper

Comment: This solution not helpful to you @temper ?